# how to fix 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape' in jypterLab

Tags: python, attributeerror, recommendation-engine

[This is my code for the music recommendatin system.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvFwt.png)

This is the Error ,.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-b58e57e00aac> in <module>
      2 print (query_index)
      3 
----> 4 distances, indices = model_knn.kneighbors(wide_artist_data.iloc[query_index, :].reshape(1, -1), n_neighbors = 6)
      5 
      6 for i in range(0, len(distances.flatten())):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Comment: Hi Devilsubarna! Welcome to StackOverflow! Next time, please copy and paste your code rather than sending a link (it helps us test it for you)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'
> ```

The [**pandas.Series.reshape**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.reshape.html) documentation says:

> Deprecated since version 0.19.0: Calling this method will raise an error. Please call
>   `.values.reshape(...)` instead.

So it would be `wide_artist_data.iloc[query_index, :].values.reshape(1, -1)`.